# Coredata performance: is there a penalty for loading many individual entities?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm working on an app that will include a set of points drawn from CLLocationManager and draw them on a map. I'll never really have a need for each point as an individual entity, they only have meaning in the context of the path.

Instead of creating a model representing the points, I could just store the path as a big JSON (or other more efficient string format) and thereby read only the single entity when it's time to pull the data out. It seems to me this could save overhead, is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that would need some testing. Finding the path directly which contains the points is probably a faster way then fetching all the points which correspond to a certain path but the part with writing them into strings seems a bit off. Parsing those strings will be slow. (JSON being a string).

For saving the points into paths I would suggest either to also add the point entity which is then linked through reference to the path. An alternative would be to use transformable data; Your point will be represented by 2 or 3 double values which could be put directly into a buffer (`NSData` for instance). The length of the data saved then defines the number of points as `data.length/(sizeof(double)*dimensions)`. This would be extremely easily done in ObjectiveC while in Swift you may lose some hair when working with raw data and unsafe pointers.

It really depends on what you are implementing but if you plan to have very many paths in the database you can still expect a large delay when fetching the data. You might want to consider creating sectors. Each sector would be represented with the same data as the region (`MKCoordinateRegion`) where on database initialize you would iterate to create sectors for the whole earth. Then when you are inserting paths you check what regions the path intersects with and assign the path to those regions (many-to-many relation). Now when you show the map you check what regions are visible and fetch only those regions and then extract paths from them.